# addEventListener. интерфейс EventListener. this

Tags: javascript, события

Подскажите пожалуйста, где найти кейс для написания объекта, который передает в качестве `listener`?

```
function someFunk(event) {
  console.log(this.a, this.b, event);
}
element.addEventListener('click', {handleEvent: someFunk, a: 1, b: 2});
```

> {handleEvent: someFunk, a: 1, b: 2}

**P.S:** Что бы не плодить много вопросов, подскажите где можно прочесть про `this` функции, которую передали в качестве `listener`? В случаи с `интерфейсом EventListener`, все иначе.

```js
document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener('click', function() {
 console.log(this); // this === elem
});
```

```css
#elem {
 text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #512;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: _где найти кейс для написания объекта, который передает в качестве listener_ - что найти?

Comment: @Igor [Что такое кейс и зачем им нужно управлять](https://habrahabr.ru/post/185858/)

Comment: @Grundy, [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), здесь ничего не говориться об this у функции и ничего не сказано о том, как создавать объект, что бы его потом передать в качестве аргумента. По поводу кейса я ответил выше.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, так и не понял что конкретно ты спрашиваешь. Про `this` я написал где описано как он устанавливается.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, как же не говорится, когда говорится: _Это должен быть объект, реализующий интерфейс EventListener_

Comment: @Grundy, я отвечал на твой комментарий который выше. сейчас вникаю в твой ответ который ниже. Можешь подсказать где найти пример написания(API) объекта в качестве интерфейса для EventListener, а то я не нашел по какому принципу они создаются. По поводу this я понял. `Передача объекта позволяет передавать дополнительные данные в обработчик, не захламляя параметры функции.`: Ты имеешь ввиду, что если передавать функцию и нужно передать дополнительные параметры, то они будут присваиваться функции, а в случаи с объектом, то просто можно создать отдельные свойства.

Comment: _если передавать функцию и нужно передать дополнительные параметры, то они будут присваиваться функции_ - не понял это предложение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74323/discussion-between---and-grundy). @Grundy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Спецификация](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-callback-interface) не рекомендует авторам стандарта определять `callback`-интерфейсы содержащие только один метод, вместо этого рекомендуется использовать `callback`-функции.

Определение `EventListener` в качестве `callback`-интерфейса является примером существующего API, который должен позволить объектам пользователя с заданным свойством (в данном случае handleEvent) считаться реализованным интерфейсом.

Для новых API и тех, для которых нет проблем с совместимостью, использование `callback`-функции позволит использовать **только объект функции** (в языке ECMAScript).

---

Передача объекта позволяет передавать дополнительные данные в обработчик, не захламляя параметры функции.

---

> *В случае с интерфейсом EventListener, все иначе.*

На самом деле все точно так же: `this` определяется в момент вызова функции.

Правила вызова описаны в [спецификации](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke)

> Call a user object’s operation with listener’s callback, "handleEvent", a list of arguments consisting of event, and **event’s currentTarget attribute value as the callback this value**

Как видно из этого пункта, в качестве `this` устанавливается значение свойства `currentTarget` из объекта `event`.